# A few AsyncTask, different login in it, effective way

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a doubt about using `AsyncTask` to communicate with a backend.
I am building an application which is communicating with my backend ( written in Python/Django ) by several `AsyncTask` eg. `LoginAsyncTask` or `GetUserWorkoutAsyncTask` and I wonder how to do it effectively - I mean to have one generic but customizable `AsyncTask` .
Should I create a callback `interface` and then pass it to the AsyncTask and `doInBackground` method or somehow I can pass method inside in it?
Or maybe there is other sufficient way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are various libraries that help with this like Volley, Retrofit, and RxJava. The DIY method is the callback approach, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don you use Volley library. You could create one singleton for GET/POST/PUT backend calls.

Volley examples :

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

You can also do it this way. Create VolleyService Singleton like this :

```
public class VolleyService {

    private static VolleyService instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private VolleyService(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url,bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static VolleyService getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VolleyService(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

And then use it for GET/POST like this in your fragment/Activity:

```
RequestQueue queue = VolleyService.getInstance(getBaseContext()).getRequestQueue();
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // we got the response, now our job is to handle it               
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //something happened, treat the error.
                Log.e("Error", error.toString());
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
```

Or you can create custom request for GET/POST like this :

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,BuildConfig.API_HOSTNAME_JSON_POST,params,  reponseListener, errorListener);
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Just to mention that Volley is doing these request sepatate thread.